# Bulk Inserting List of Dictionary Objects into Postgres with Upsert

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a list of dictionary objects I parse from a CSV file. The issue at hand is the CSV just grows longer because new data gets appended onto it. **I have no control over this**. However I need to bulk insert the new records into Postgres but I also have to deny duplicates and check for any changes to existing records. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: how is schema of your csv and table?

Comment: What do you have to do when you find changes?  Could you just truncate the table and reload "from scratch" each time?

Comment: @jjanes You saying drop the table each time and reinsert? I could but I feel like that's a lot of overhead. When I find changes I need to update. If there is no matching record then I need to upsert.  And @GiovaniSalazar it's just  `building_id,first_name,last_name`. Cut down for brevity. Nothing special

Comment: @Dave can we use constraints group of column (building_id,first_name,last_name) for  to take the control about records unique ?....and have you see psycopg2 like tool for load csv to tables ...?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar there will actually be 3 unique keys to determine duplicate. Let's say  (building_id, group_id, user_id, first_name, last_name). Out of those columns of the first three match you know you will have a duplicate. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: I think all solutions are going to have high overhead in some sense or another.  The drop/truncate at least has the virtue of simplicity.  What overhead are you trying to spare?  CPU?  Disk writes in general?  WAL writes in particular?